# Any way to find out which TField is raising EDBClient with message 'Field value required.'?

Tags: delphi, exception, tclientdataset

I have one TClientDataSet with several Fields and I'm getting this exception, I'm sure that I forgot to set one field value, but the question is, which Field?

Is there some way to find out quickly which field is raising this exception?

**EDIT**

I solved the problem, I was connecting the TClientDataSet to the wrong provider, which had a required field on the server but didn't have this field on the client.

But it still doesn't invalidate my question, I lost a lot of time to figure it out, and if I had some way to know which server side required field was raising this error it would be very quick to realise what was my mistake.

**EDIT 2**

Related QCs:

[#5557](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=5557) - Solved as "As Designed".

[#54380](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=54380) - Open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the debugger notifies you of the exception, look at the call stack. Navigate to the routine that is iterating over the list of fields, and inspect the loop-control variable at that point to find out how far through the field list your program got before raising an exception.

If the loop-control variable isn't accurate, then set a breakpoint in that routine and re-run your program. Step through until you get the exception again.

Another option is to look at all the fields and see for yourself which one lacks a value.

Comment: The problem is that I can't debug it, it is raised by and stdcall on TClientDataSet's InternalPost, it passes the validation of TDataSet's InternalPost method.

Comment: So, are you saying you can't reproduce the problem on your own computer? If the problem happens on your computer, then you can debug it.

Comment: No, what I'm saying is: it is raised in line 2861 in DBClient.pas, which has this code: Check(FDSCursor.InsertRecord(ActiveBuffer)); the funcion InsertRecord is:

    function InsertRecord(          { Insert new record }
        pRecBuf  : Pointer
    ): DBResult; stdcall;

And if I'm not mistaken, is from midas, so, how do I debug it?